# Hyper-V and Network settings for colocation

Tags: hyper-v, gateway, subnet, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm currently in the process of colocating a windows server 2008 r2 running 3 hyper-v machines.

The co-location company has advised me to make the following example changes to my server:

For example IP Address: 83.145.229.65

Setup the IP Address on the server to be that of the one we have supplied and set your DNS as below:

1. Subnet: 255.255.255.0
2. Gateway: 83.145.229.1
3. Primary DNS: 87.117.198.200
4. Secondary DNS: 87.117.237.100
5. Tertiary DNS: 87.117.196.200

I have done made the changes above for the host server, but I assume I have to make identical changes to the hyper-v machines?

Does the Gateway last value increment for each machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your VM's will be having similar External IP's in the same range (So I assume you have been given a range of IP's) then the gateway would be the same for all VM's.

Comment: I have only been given a single IP address. Would I need 3 additional ones or could I get by with just a single IP address to use on the Hyper-v's?

Comment: That depends if you want external access to each of the VM's, if you do then each will need their own routable IP.

Comment: If I didn't I assume they would still be able to access the internet? How would I then apply the settings above to these hyper-v's using the single ip address assuming that individual routable ip's aren't required?

Comment: Well you would need the host to have both an External and Internal IP address and for it to act as a gateway between the two networks

Comment: In your opinion would it just be easier/better to have 4 different IP addresses. 1 for the host server and 3 for the hyper-v's?

Comment: Yep, that would be the easiest option.

Comment: Ok Sam, thank you for your patience in answering. Final question if I couldn't get additional IP addresses and had to use the single IP address of 83.145.229.65 on the host with an internal of say 192.168.0.1 how is that set as the gateway to the Hyper-v's, what are their settings then? Also are these internal IP's dynamic?

Comment: You would need some way of routing between the internal and external networks, most likley you would need to setup your hyper-v host to do this using RRAS, or enabling routing for all interfaces on the host, take a look at this article for more detail - http://www.dscoduc.com/2009/09/hyper-v-routing-without-a-router-vm/